# Can't retrieve multi mysql query value in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 3 queries like this in my **Controller** function:

```
function getDataDetail(Request $request) 
{
    $id = $request->get('id');

    $taskData['taskData'] = DB::select("SELECT NAME_, PRIORITY_, ASSIGNEE_, DUE_DATE_, START_TIME_, END_TIME_, PROC_DEF_ID_ FROM act_hi_taskinst WHERE PROC_INST_ID_ LIKE '%$id%'");

    $varData['varData'] = DB::select("SELECT NAME_, TEXT_ FROM act_hi_varinst WHERE PROC_INST_ID_ LIKE '%$id%'");

    $imagepath['imagepathData'] = DB::connection('mysql_2')->select("SELECT imagePath FROM images WHERE processInstanceId = $id");

    if(count($taskData) > 0 && count($varData) > 0 && count($imagepath) > 0) {
        return view('datatrackingdetail', $taskData, $varData, $imagepath);
    } else {
        return view('datatrackingdetail');
    }
}
```

And I retrieve query value in my view by foreach loop. Problem is my code work fine with only 2 query variables in if function, if there are 3 query variables in my code and it's not work, **error** say:

> "Undefined variable imagepathData" in my view.

How should I fix it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you created this `mysql_2` in `app/config` under `'connections'` array ?

Comment: yes, i created. If I delete any query variable, 2 others work fine. I really don't understand what's wrong with this :(

Comment: What is the output of this `dd($imagepath)` ?

Comment: it's my image link: array:1 [▼
  "imagepath" => array:1 [▼
    0 => {#218 ▼
      +"imagePath": "images\8345.png"
    }
  ]
]

Comment: What is the default db in `app/config` ? `'default' => env('DB_DEFAULT', 'mysql')`

Comment: it's 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189788/discussion-between-vipertecpro-and-tomato).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DB::connection('mysql_2')->table('images')->select("imagePath")->where(['processInstanceId' => $id]);
```

Or you shoud use raw select in your query